# Windows Server 2019 Audio only working with Remote Connection

Tags: windows, audio, audio-streaming, windows-server-2019

Currently i'm trying to set up a livestream on a remote server. This server doesn't have a sound card or anything, so right now i only get sound when i use my own sound card on a other pc. The problem is, i only get sound in the livestream, when i make a remote control to this server, but afterwards when i stop the remote connection, the sound isn't in the livestream anymore. As an example, i start the Windows media player with some music during remote control. I stream it with obs and the music is there. Afterwards i close the remote control and now the sound isn't there anymore. When i connect again, i get the message, that the audio device was disconnected. It makes sense, but how can i have sounds also afterwards?

In order to simulate sound, i tried various things like VB-Audio Virtual Cable, e2eSoft VSC, Virtual Audio Cable and some others but they all do not seem to work on Windows Server 2019. When i install them, they are in the device manager, but i can't set them anywhere nor can i use them anywhere as audio output. I tried so many different software, but they all are outdated and don't work.

So does anybody have an idea, how to solve this and with what? Thanks to all answers.

Comment: Do you have "Windows Audio" service (`Audiosrv`) turned on? Long time ago I had similar problem with some Windows Server 2003 edition, where this service was turned off permanently in Windows Services by default after OS installation, no matter if there was sound card or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the zip file from VB Audio Cable is locked and unlock it.

That did the trick for me.